# What is the span of an infinite set?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

If a subset $W$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$, I want to show that $\operatorname{span}(W)=W$.

But is it possible to define $\operatorname{span}(W)$? $W$ can either be a finite or infinite set and according to what I know $\operatorname{span}(W)$ can only be defined on a finite set $W$.

Is there any problem with my argument?

Answer (score 12):

The span of $W$ is all vectors produced from (finite) linear combinations
of vectors in $W$. That is to say,
$$
\operatorname{span}(W)=\left\{ \alpha_{1}w_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}w_{n}\colon n\geq 1,\text{ }\{\alpha_{i}\}\subset K\text{, }\{w_{i}\}\subset W\right\} .
$$
So yes, the span of an infinite set is well-defined. $K$ is the underlying scalar field (e.g. $K=\mathbb{R}$ if your scalars are real numbers).

Comment: Drat, beat me to it! +1.

Comment: Haha, dang, I hate it when people do that to me! I'm sorry >_<

Comment: If you think mine or Noah's solution was sufficient, press the checkmark on either of them to accept ( and generalize this approach to any question asked on Math.SE ;) )

Comment: Does this notation mean that for all $n \geq 1$ or we choose some $n$?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov: $v$ is in the span of $W$ if there exists $n \geq 1$, $\{ \alpha_i \}_{i=1}^n \subset K$, and $\{ w_i \}_{i=1}^n \subset W$ such that $v = \alpha_1 w_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n w_n$. In other words, we *choose* $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Span is defined for all sets of vectors: if $X\subseteq V$, then $Span(X)$ is the set of vectors which can be written as linear combinations of elements of $W$.

Now, in each *specific* linear combination, only finitely many vectors from $X$ can be used, so in that sense span is "about" finite sets; but $Span(X)$ is still defined, and will in general be wildly different from $Span(F)$ for any finite $F\subseteq X$. (Example: let $X$ be any infinite set of mutually transcendental reals, as a subspace of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}$.)