# Let $V$ be the space of polynomial functions over the field $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that the set $S = \{1, x, x^2, \dots\}$ is a basis for V.

Tags: linear-algebra

Please provide the step by step solution to prove that the infinite set $S = \{1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots\}$ is Linearly Independent & $\operatorname{Span}(S) = V$, both.

If $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$ and $S$ is a subset of $V$, then $S$ is called the basis of $V$ if (a) $S$ is linearly independent and (b) $\operatorname{Span}(S) = V$.
Both conditions have to be satisfied.
I have no idea how to from that an infinite set is linearly independent. All I've heard is that an infinite set $S$ is linearly independent if all the finite subsets of S are linearly independent.

Comment: What is your thought on this?Add what you have done so far

Comment: Add your own efforts: at least definitions, what must be proved, etc., lest your post will be downvoted and probably also closed.

Comment: What is your definition of a basis of a vector space? Is it a generating and independent collection of vectors?

Comment: Enough context has now been added : the question looks like a duplicate but I can't locate one as of yet. Thank you @AaravArya for the edits.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
I usually am against providing just a hint as an answer, but I'm unsure what you've tried, so my hands are tied. You've said that you dont know how to deal with the fact that $S$ is an infinite set, but you can actually circumvent this issue.

I'll explain a little bit better. You need to prove that $\mathrm{span}(S) = V$. The best way to do this, is to take some element $x\in\mathrm{span}(S)$ and show that $x\in V$. Similarly, take some $x\in V$ and show that $x\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Hence, $V = \mathrm{span}(S)$. To select some $x\in V$ just suppose that $\mathrm{deg}(x)=n$ for some arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{N}$. In that way, you essentially don't need to deal with the fact that the basis of $V$ is infinite, because you only need the first $n$ elements to represent it. (We are essentially taking an arbitrary subset of $S$ here, like you said.)

To prove that the set is linearly independent, you need to demonstrate that any linear combination of $S$ is zero if and only if it's the zero polynomial. To prove this, once again take some linear combination of $S$ and suppose (WLOG) that the resultant polynomial $p$ has degree $n$. Then, suppose this polynomial is identically zero.

Heuristically, if any of the coefficients of $p$ is not zero, then $p$ will admit values that are not zero. But we supposed that it was *identically* zero. Contradiction. Hence, all coefficients are zero. You will need to make this argumnet quite a bit more rigorous but this should be enough for you to realise what to do.

> To do this rigorously, suppose some coefficient $a_k$ is not equal to zero. Then, differentiate $p$, $k$ times. We can do this because the field in which our vector is over is $\mathbb{R}$. Then, evaluate the resultant polynomial at zero. We will be left with $a_k = 0$, which is a contradiction.

If we started off with all coefficients equal to zero, then of course we have the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

An idea that probably will make your problem a little easier: a polynomial $\;p(x)\;$ can be written in the following general fashion:

$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;a_k=0\;\;\text{for all but a finite number of indices}\;\;k=0,1,2,...$$

By this definition there is a maximal index $\;n\;$ for which $\;a_n\neq0\;$ , and we thus define $\;\deg p=n\;$ . Observe also that by this definition it is very easy to define that for two polynomials $\;p,\,g\;$ we have

$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k=g(x)\iff a_k=b_k\;\;\forall\,k=0,1,2,...$$

and from here we get at once that

$$h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^l=0\iff c_k=0\;\;\forall\,k=0,1,2,3,...$$

and this last already gives us that $\;S\;$ is l.i....!

Well, using the above we get naturally that

$$\deg p=n\implies p(x)\in\text{Span}\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}\subset\text{ Span} S$$

and we get that $\;S\;$ is a generator set of $\;V\;$, so altogether we get $\;S\;$ is a basis of $\;V\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

Your definition for linear independence of an infinite set of vectors is sound. The linear span of an infinite set of vectors is similarly taken to be the set of all linear combinations of finitely many vectors in the set, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638330/what-is-the-span-of-an-infinite-set#:%7E:text=The%20span%20of%20W%20is,wi%7D%E2%8A%82W%7D.).

Non-zero linear combination of vectors of any finite subset of $S$, say $T=\{x^{i_1},x^{i_2},...,x^{i_m}\}$ is a non-zero polynomial with finitely many zeroes. Thus it cannot be identically zero. If it is identically zero, then it must be the zero polynomial with all coefficients zero. This gives that $S$ is a set of linearly independent vectors. Proving that $S$ spans the set of all polynomials should not be a big deal.